# Is there a difference between 0.18 and 0.180 seconds?

Tags: time

Q. Is there a difference between 0.18 and 0.180 seconds ?

In our databases we are collecting timestamps and there are 2 time instants which are the same for the hour, minute and seconds but the milliseconds field is being returned as:

- 0.18
- 0.177

Comment: Is this a question about IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic? Or what? Because among the real numbers, "0.18" and "0.180" are both the rational number 9/50, but of course many computers may have different the same or different representations of the numbers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics, but about numerical representations of numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When scientists report a measurement of 0.18, it usually means they are certain the actual value they've measured is between 0.175 and 0.185.

When scientists report a measurement of 0.180, it usually means they are certain the actual value they've measured is between 0.1795 and 0.1805.

When scientists report a measurement of 0.177, it usually means they are certain the actual value they've measured is between 0.1765 and 0.1775.

How you should interpret those numbers in your database is be a question for the person who put those numbers there, but without other available information, that's the interpretation I would default to.

Comment: This. Following (correctly) the conventions about recording numbers can make the difference significant, but reading the difference as significant when the writer *wasn't* following them is an error. It's about communication.